# VB.Net - What is the difference between AssemblyFileVersion & AssemblyFileVersionAttribute and AssemblyVersion & AssemblyVersionAttribute

Tags: vb.net, versioning, assemblyinfo, assemblyversionattribute, assemblyfileversion

I've inherited a VB.Net codebase which was VB 2005 and upgraded to VB 2008 consisting of around 100 projects

I'm trying to re-version all of the components but have discovered some of the AssemblyInfo.vb files have an `AssemblyFileVersion` entry and some have an `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` entry.

Also, some have an `AssemblyVersion` entry and some have an `AssemblyVersionAttribute` entry.

What is the difference between with and without `Attribute`?

Which ones should I be using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. Just as `int` will resolve to `System.Int32`, any type derived from `Attribute` is treated specially by the compiler. So...

`[MyCustom]` will resolve to `[MyCustomAttribute]`

[Relavent MSDN Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)

> By convention, all attribute names end
>   with the word "Attribute" to
>   distinguish them from other items in
>   the .NET Framework. However, you do
>   not need to specify the attribute
>   suffix when using attributes in code.
>   For example, [DllImport] is equivalent
>   to [DllImportAttribute], but
>   DllImportAttribute is the attribute's
>   actual name in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Lol, it really doesn't matter either way :) Rep is nice, but it's not why I answer questions on SO.

Answer (score 4):

`AssemblyFileVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` etc are the same thing and you can use either one. [Here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/510139/assemblyfileversion-vs-assemblyfileversionattribute)'s a response from Microsoft on their connect website about this.

Comment: @Shevek: I'd go with Josh's answer since he got the most upvotes and obviously put in more effort than my answer.