# VB.Net - Version numbering in VBPROJ file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Following on from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109848/vb-net-what-is-the-difference-between-assemblyfileversion-assemblyfileversion), are the `AssemblyMajorVersion`, `AssemblyMinorVersion`, `AssemblyRevisionNumber` and `GenerateRevisionNumber` properties required in `.vbproj` files?

All of our components have these entries in the `.vbproj` files but they are completely out of sync with the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` entries in the `AssemblyInfo.vb` files.

Are they a legacy from the upgrade from previous VS versions?

Can I just remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the authorative answer but seems like legacy, none of the VS2005 .vbproj files I looked at have them and they don't get many hits on google and one of the places I did get a hit is in a sample file to *Programming Microsoft® Windows® with C#* which was published in Dec 2001 it seems.

You could try to compile the assembly, make a copy of it, remove those attributes and then re-compile and do a file compare on the assemblies and see if they're identical.

Comment: good idea, I'll give that a try.. I think they are legacy from VB4 or VB6 - these components have been through the mill: VB4 -> VB6 -> VB.Net 2003 -> VB.Net 2005 -> VB.Net 2008 (and soon VB.Net 2010 if I get my way!)